# Multiple related question titles

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, titles

I am creating a programming language, **Linny**, and have asked two questions ([First Question Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224907/linny-an-interpreted-programming-language), [Second Question Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225051/linny-continued-language-development)). As I continue to improve the language, I intend on asking more questions to review the new code. I'm having problems about how I should format the next few questions I'm going to ask. How should I format the question title to make it clear it's the newest version of the code, without having the titles be basically the same and possibly spam? Should I format my titles like:

- Linny: Language Development Stage 3
- Linny: Language Development Stage 4
- etc..

But I feel like the titles are too closely related and could be flagged as spam, annoying to some users, or uninteresting. Let me know if I am allowed to do this, so I can edit my titles accordingly. In the future, is this title scheme for a topic that contains multiple questions acceptable? Thank you for your time in reading this.

Comment: Maybe something like "Linny Language Stage 2: Functions and Flow Control" -- a word or two about what's new since last version?

Comment: Remember that the title should state _what your code does_, so maybe something like "Reversing the Polarity of the Neutron Flow (Linny Stage 3)".

Comment: @user11536834 That would be much, much better than the current suggestion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Let me know if I am allowed to do this

You're allowed to do this, and it has been done before. *However*, it's not a particularly good idea with regards to question clarity and quality. This is one of those cases where if you *can* do it better, you probably *should* do it better.

Examples that such a scheme has been done before:

- [JSON Test Harness: Part 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/205353)
- [JSON Test Harness: Part 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/205355)
- [JSON Test Harness: Part 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/205356)
- [JSON Test Harness: Part 4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/205357)

What in my opinion a better approach would be, and already suggested by  [user11536834](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/multiple-related-question-titles#comment19766_9263), is telling a little more about *what's* been done in this iteration:

- [Speech Recognition Part 1: Generate Training Data](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/160958/52915)
- [Speech Recognition Part 2: Classifying Data](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/161273/52915)
- [Speech Recognition Part 3: Training the Neural Network](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/162792/52915)

All of a sudden you have a descriptive title while still having similar enough titles to identify the questions as being part of a group.

Minor note: titles really shouldn't Be Fully Capitalized because that makes them unnecessarily hard to read, but blame the papers for setting the wrong example...